# Authorization based on user's class (role/member) with mysql

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio, asp.net-roles, asp.net-authorization

I used to edit `Web.config` before in order to allow some users to access some pages/folder, eg:

```
  <location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users ="?" />
        <allow users ="Administrator" />
        <deny users ="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

That is quite smart and straightforward.

Now I need to allow a *class* of users to access some folders. Unfortunately, it seems not such easy as it is for single users. I read about **roles** and **members** but I only found official documentation about implementing that with a MSSQL database.

What is the most straightforward way to set up a roles/members based authorization with a MySql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html or search "asp.net membership mysql"

Comment: Thanks, setting it up was a bit tricky but it was indeed what I was looking for.